# Sidebar's height equal to main content

Tags: css, height, equals

I am editing a wordpress theme [here](http://nl.italiethuis.com/category/territory/lazio/). I have a problem with the sidebar height.

How can I make the right sidebar as tall as the the main content?

PLEASE NOTE: the sidebar is kept FLUID with a "overflow: auto" parameter.

Comment: @SVS it's the "footer"... Also, `.container` has a width of `960px`. You can't have that in the sidebar and still keep it a "sidebar"

Comment: Sorry, it is cleaner now. The sidebar is back into place and I have removed the container div inside the sidebar, it was useless as sachleen pointed out.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are a couple of techniques for equal-height columns, I normally like [this one by Alex Robinson](http://www.positioniseverything.net/articles/onetruelayout/equalheight) on **Position Everything**:

> How?
>
> The basic method works like this:
>
> 1. Blocks which will act as columns must be wrapped in a container
>      element
> 2. Apply **overflow: hidden** to the container element
> 3. Apply **padding-bottom: $big_value** to the column blocks, where $big_value is a large enough value to guarantee that it's equal to
>      or larger than the tallest column
> 4. Apply **margin-bottom: -$big_value** to the column blocks

The CSS would look something like this:

```
 #block_1, #block_2, #block_3 {
     padding-bottom: 32767px;
     margin-bottom: -32767px;
 }

 #wrapper {
     overflow: hidden;
 }
```

And the HTML:

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="block_1">
        <p>Content goes here</p>
    </div>
    <div id="block_2">
        <p>Content goes here</p>
    </div>
    <div id="block_3">
        <p>Content goes here</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Uhm, I tried it but it is not working... the wrapper height ("main-content") is now 0... http://nl.italiethuis.com/category/territory/lazio/

Comment: At line #105 in your stylesheet, you're overriding the large padding bottom set at #100 tp 20px with this declartion: "**padding: 40px 20px 20px 20px;**". This is pulling the content below over the left-hand area via the negative margin.

If you want a 20px bottom padding on the <div>, to use this method, you'd have to incorporate it into the declaration by setting the negative margin to 20px less than the padding-bottom used. (So padding-bottom: 32767px; margin-bottom: -32747px).

Comment: Great, it works. I also set the padding left & top for the two column blocks but this makes their heights to grow a lot (guess they're 32767px tall now... :D)

Comment: OK, you're not there yet — you've set the bottom margin to -3277px, i.e. about 10% of what it should be! :)

You'll also want something to get the two columns to display side-by-side, e.g. float left applied to both. Check out the CSS I've used on the JSFiddle above.

Comment: Oh I see, that's why. Do you notice now though that there is still the scrollbar?

Comment: In Chrome, your sidebar is now completely underneath the LHS content — this seems to be because the width that you're setting on #left-area takes up too much room to allow #right-area to sit alongside it. 

I'd suggest stripping it back — get the two columns to display alongside each other with the content in. Once you have this the way you want it, then apply styles for the internal spacing of both.

Comment: It's due to #left-area's margin-left (set to 25%). I want to have the left-area centered but "margin: 0 auto" doesn't work to me when having the liquid sidebar and I have to use the margin-left property. If I low down the margin-left to 20% is OK? Whic res is your monitor?

Comment: I'm using 1920x1080, and yes, it displays fine now. 

But now that we miles and miles from the original topic & I'm just doing QA work on your CSS, I'm going have to leave it there I'm afraid or my boss won't be too happy ;)

Good luck with the site!

Comment: Hi, I am here again as I am having an issue with this solution: in those pages where there are just few rows of text (= text is less longer than the viewport, I think), the equalized columns extend far more down than the viewport itself. Watch [this page](http://nl.italiethuis.com/credits/) for example. Is this a known issue or is it solvable? Thank you...

Comment: Hi Niccolò. Remove: `#main-content{ min-height: 100% }, #left-area{ display:inline-block; margin-left: -260px }, #right-area{ position:absolute; display: inline-block; width: 100% }`. Set `#left-area, #right-area{float: left}`. With respect, if you make sweeping changes to a solution (e.g. taking the sidebar out of the document flow by positioning it absolutely!) it is unreasonable to expect that solution to still work. If you want to use a certain solution to a problem it will always impact what approaches you can then use for formatting the rest of the page — you can't carry on regardless.

Comment: the problem is both the right-area's (sidebar) and left-area's backgrounds must be fluid while The left-area's and right-area's content must remain at the center of the screen.

Comment: You could possibly centre the #main-products div by absoluting positioning it relative to the #main-content rather than #left-area, but you may need to change your mark-up to better achieve what you're after. You're no longer asking a specific question however & are now just looking for advice on your coding.

Comment: Thank you, I am reverting back to the previous layout as I don't have enough time to do everything from scratch.